# JavaScript 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, undefined

sort of an easy one. Can you help me in explaining why the line the 
"console.log("test", nn) })", is showing nn as undefined rather than the value 3? Thank you much. Here is the code snippet.

```
function unless(test, then) {
  if (!test) then();
}
function repeat(times, body) {
  for (var i = 0; i < times; i++) body(i);
}

repeat(3, function(n) {
  var nn = unless(n % 2, function() {
    return 1 * 3
  });
  console.log("test", nn)
});
```

Comment: `unless()` doesn't return anything.

Comment: @Juhana That comment should be an answer.

Comment: This question should be closed instead of answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `unless()` function does not return anything.  Thus

```
var nn = unless(...);
```

means that `nn` will just be `undefined`.  For `nn` to have a value, your `unless()` function must return a value.

In here:

```
function unless(test, then) {
  if (!test) then();
}
```

There is no `return` statement.  The callback `then()` might return a value, but that just makes that value available within `unless()` if you assigned it to something.  If you want `unless()` itself to return a value, you need to add one or more appropriate `return` statements.

For example, you could fix part of the problem by just returning the `then()` value such as:

```
function unless(test, then) {
  if (!test) return then();
}
```

But, you still need a return value for the case where `test` is truthy.  I'm not sure what you want that return value to be in that case so I don't know what to recommend, but the general form could be this:

```
function unless(test, then) {
  if (!test) {
      return then();
  } else {
      return somethingelse;   // assign some return value when `test` is truthy
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I appreciate it. This is very helpful

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to assign nn from the result of the function `unless` currently `unless()` returns `undefined`, and therefore the result of the expression is `undefined`.

The return in your callback function `then()` is not in the scope for `nn` to capture the result, it returns to the scope of `unless()` which has no return statement, meaning that `var nn` will yield undefined due to nothing being returned.

In order to fix this, when you perform the recursive part of your algorithm you should assign to a variable in the scope of `unless()` and then return that:

```
function unless(test, then) {
    var result = test;
    if (!test) { 
        result = then(); 
    }
    return result;
}
function repeat(times, body) {
  for (var i = 0; i < times; i++) body(i);
}

repeat(3, function(n) {
  var nn = unless(n % 2, function() {
    return 1 * 3
  });
  console.log("test", nn)
});
```

Now returns `3, 1, 3`

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki There is no difference.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Not for me, for JavaScript. You could argue that "nothing" is `undefined` by testing `(function(arg){console.log(arg===undefined)})()` - you pass "nothing" to the function, compare it to `undefined`, and it yields `true`. Therefore, "nothing" equals `undefined`.

Comment: @Siguza amended my answer, as you said nothing is truly undefined is a valid point.  Although its always best to handle the `undefined` case elegantly